# Import a file having a column with maximum 720 characters in length

Tags: sql-server

I'm using import and export wizard. File type is xlsx.
But there is a column "address" which is causing problem.
it has maximum size of 720 in length . 
It gets identified as nvarchar type and when I import it, error is:

> Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Source - _xlnm#_FilterDatabase.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[street 1/address] on Source - _xlnm#_FilterDatabase.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[image: Picture of variable mappings]

Answer (score 0):

There is a `size` property, adjust it to your needs from 255 to 720

Comment: i have changed the size of 255 to 720 and then sql automatically converted it to varchar and size max but still the same issue

Comment: And what about `or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.`? Are these lines have the same [Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15)?